# Read XML Data back into flex components

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Please help

I can save the data from the three components as xml and it works, but now I am struggling with the code to read that data back into the components when the user opens. This is a local file that is created by the user. I need help with the open event handler.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="734" height="389"
                       creationComplete="init();">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        public var xmlData:XML=<ROOTS></ROOTS>;

        private function fnAddItem():void
        {
        var fr:FileReference = new FileReference(); 

        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        var newXmlRow:XML=<ROOTS>
        <TXT>{txt1.text}</TXT>
        <TXTA>{txt2.text}</TXTA>
        <DTF>{txt3.text}</DTF>
        </ROOTS>;
        ba.writeMultiByte(newXmlRow, 'utf-8');
        fr.save(ba);
        }


            protected function oped_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
                var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                var newXmlRow:XML=<ROOTS>
                        <TXT>{txt1.text}</TXT>
                        <TXTA>{txt2.text}</TXTA>
                        <DTF>{txt3.text}</DTF>
                        </ROOTS>;
                ba.readMultiByte(xmlData, 'utf-8');
                fr.load(ba);

            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label x="108" y="80" text="Name"/>
    <s:Label x="91" y="222" text="Remarks"/>
    <s:Label x="108" y="116" text="text"/>
    <s:TextInput id="txt1" x="167" y="78"/>
    <s:TextArea id="txt2" x="167" y="218" height="86"/>
    <s:TextArea id="txt3" x="167" y="108" height="77"/>

    <s:Button x="53" y="242" label="save" width="90" click="fnAddItem()"/>
    <s:Button id="oped" x="73" y="271" label="open" click="oped_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first if you want a dialog you have to wait for the user to make a selection. The selection throws an event that you can catch. Within the handler you can do the file handling. Try if the following code works for you.

```
    private var openedFile:File;

    private function oped_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        openedFile = new File();
        openedFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, file_select);
        openedFile.browseForOpen("Please select a file...");
    }

    private function file_select(event:Event):void {
        if(openedFile != null && openedFile.exists){
            var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fileStream.open(openedFile, FileMode.READ);
            var readXML:XML = XML(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));
            fileStream.close();
            trace(readXML.toString());
            txt1.text = readXML.TXT;
            txt2.text = readXML.TXTA;
            txt3.text = readXML.DTF;
        }
        trace(event);
    }
```

cheers,
rob

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks so much for this. I have spend days on this issue, and was given classes and models and all sorts to get this right. I knew there was a simple way and this works exactly like I wanted. THANKS. Is there a way I can help you with, you have no Idea how happy I am right now!